# HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFormatString Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink

I have GridView with "HyperLinkField", when I click on one of the several names in the table this lead me to another page. Then I want to show some information about the clicked item. Here in this code I describe that I want whatever row I have clicked, new page to be opened and to get FirstName clicked field from the previous page. I need some more information about this field in the code:

What exactly this field does ?

```
DataNavigateUrlFormatString="Page.aspx?FirstName={0}" />
```

and to be more specific this one: "FirstName={0}" />"

```
<asp:HyperLinkField 
 DataTextField="FirstName" 
 HeaderText="First Name"
 DataNavigateUrlFields="FirstName" 
 DataNavigateUrlFormatString="Page.aspx?FirstName={0}" />
```

How to get this clicked field from the previous page in the new page ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{0}` is placeholder to replace the desired value. in above example datanavigateurlformatstring works with conjuction of  datanavigateurlfields. it will replace DataNavigateUrlFields value. [DataNavigateUrlFormatString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield.datanavigateurlformatstring.aspx)

Note :

> the The format string is applied only when the DataNavigateUrlFields
>   property is set.

```
datanavigateurlfields="ProductID"
datanavigateurlformatstring="~\details.aspx?ProductID={0}"
```

Use cases

1. Mostly used in Gridview or Listview, where you need dynamic link, based on the datafield.
2. it's as same as adding the querystring manually for each hyperlink.

to Uses This values in other page, you can access the `Request` property.

```
if(Request["ProductID"]!=null)
var productID=Request["ProductID"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

The {0} placeholder in [DataNavigateUrlFormatString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield.datanavigateurlformatstring.aspx) is replaced with the field's value in the HyperLinkField object. In your code, it will replaced with FirstName value